# Websites for Latin pronunciation?

Tags: pronunciation

The only one I've found so far is Google Translate. Is Google's Latin pronunciation good/reliable? If not, what are some other resources?

Example from Google: [*ceteris paribus*](https://translate.google.com/#la/en/ceteris%20paribus) (click on the  icon).

(Context: I know close to nothing about Latin and am interested only because Latin phrases are sometimes used in English.)

Comment: Welcome to the site! Our policy on broad resource request questions is that they should first be proposed at [this meta question](http://meta.latin.stackexchange.com/q/188/79) instead of asking directly. See the banner in the [dictionary question](http://latin.stackexchange.com/q/867/79), for example. Latin pronunciation is a broad topic, and "correct" pronunciation depends on time, place, and context. If you only want comments on Google's pronunciation, the question is fine. If you want online tools for pronunciation, I think it should go through the meta page.

Comment: You may know this already, but there are several options for pronouncing Latin phrases in English: pronouncing them in a rough approximation of Classical Latin pronunciation is only one of them. There are different arguments for each one; for example, I tend to value consistency over phonetic closeness to classical pronunciation, so I'd rather pronounce the "c" in *ceteris paribus* as /s/ to match the established English pronunciations of *et cetera* and *Caesar.* You're unlikely to hear that in any website for Latin-language pronunciation, though.

Comment: Hi Kenny!  As Joonas mentioned, this question is too broad to work well in a Q&A like this one.  As a result, I've just put it on hold – but that's not permanent.  Here are ways you could get it reopened: 1) Narrow the question to ask for reviews of Google Translate only, or more specifically tell us what *kind* of website you are looking for, with details.  2) Propose a pronunciation website question on [the resource meta question](http://meta.latin.stackexchange.com/q/188/12).  Hope this makes sense – feel free to add any questions or comments you have in a new comment here.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I shouldn't trust Google translate for pronunciation, it often pronounces words/sentences wrong. I would recommend to learn how to pronounce Latin words yourself.

I would recommend [this](http://www.preces-latinae.org/thesaurus/Introductio/Pronunciatio.html) and/or 
[this](http://www.orbilat.com/Languages/Latin/Grammar/Latin-Pronunciation-Syllable-Accent.html) site.

The most automatic pronunciation sites aren't reliable: it are computers, 99% of all the automatic translators/pronunciators has got a few bugs/errors that the pronunciation isn't optimal. You could use automatic translators, but you can't trust 100% on them. So my advice: learn the pronunciation yourself.

If you really don't want to learn it yourself, then I would recommend [this](https://www.howtopronounce.com/latin/index.php) automatic site, but again: it doesn't pronounce all words right.

Answer (score 3):

**For the pronunciation of post Classical Latin:**
*Singing Early Music*:  0253210267 claims that on their disc (with the book)

> "A specialist presents  each  of  the  languages  or dialects 
>   included,  which  are  English, Scots, French,  Occitan,  Catalan, 
>   Spanish,   Portuguese,   Galician- Portuguese, Italian, German,  and
>   Flemish, **as well as the characteristic Latin**  of  each  area; 
>   sample  texts  can  be  heard  on  an  included compact disc." *(emphasis not in the original)*

This implies that Latin pronunciation changed distinctively region by region across Europe, and century by century from classical to renaissance.

This is accessible as a [Google book](https://books.google.fr/books?id=ltDo50IzGpIC), so not really a website; simply for this specialist field of local medieval sung Latin, the subject is being researched and the results are available here and elsewhere  if you need them.